# How transform a non-standard text to JSON

Tags: java, json

I read a PDF file and it returns a String format in a variable. The big problem is this text *isn't standardized*, it comes with several different delimiters such as periods (.), colon (:), commas (,), dashes (-), line breaks (\n), for separate the information. For a better view let's use this example:

```
String text = "Info1: lorem Info2 - lorem, Info3 = lorem \n\n Info4>lorem";
```

I'd like to separate the information in JSON format, for example:

```
{
   "Info1" : "lorem",
   "Info2" : "lorem",
   "Info3" : "lorem",
   "Info4" : "lorem",
}
```

*I'm doing several splits to go separating part by part.*
**Is there any other way to make the information in this file JSON easier and "clean" (library or other tool) or i'm in the right way?**

Comment: Try to clarify your question. It doesn't matter from where string is taken, you need transform String to JSON with some requirements. Just ask question about that with input and output examples

Comment: @Javasick i edited my question, what do you think?

Comment: I am afraid the entire intelligence resides in your attempts to convert the text. Advisable is to conserve the original text, say gzip compressed and then base64 converted to tex as extra field: `"original" : "5bJ934/huE+56p"`maybe with a version of your conversion code, so you can repair older versions.

Comment: Perfect. Hope, you'll find the right answer